# idhttp get string and convert it to Integer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, idhttp

i am trying to get string from url and convert it to integer

i am doing something like this

```
var
stringtoget : string;
stringint : integer;

stringtoget := IdHTTP1.Get('http://url/text.txt');

stringint := strToint(stringtoget );
```

But i get the following exception

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message
>   ''26655 ' is not a valid integer value'.

any idea what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trailing space on the string. That can be seen in the error message. Remove it with `Trim` before converting.

Comment: Or use `IndyStrToInt()` (in the `IdGlobal` unit), which does the trimming for you.